# Why using integer as a key with pymongo doesn't work?

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

I've tried this with a larger data set in python and had issues, so i created a small test set, also in python with pymongo:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
testColl = MongoClient().tDB.tColl
data = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': {1: {'a': 'B'}}, '_id': 'AB123456789'}
testColl.insert(data)
```

This returns

```
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: documents must have only string keys, key was 1
```

replacing the 1 in the dictionary in baz with a 2 changes the error to key was 2 accordingly

Why is this? Am I missing something about ids in Mongo?

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory: you must use `string` as keys only. Take a look at [this question for guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811486/pymongo-saving-embedded-objectids-invaliddocumenterror).

Comment: I read that question before and I still don't understand. I have an _id at the top level and its a string. Why does pymongo reject it in favor of the key for an inner dictionary? I'm probably missing something, and I might need an eli5 before I get it at this point.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've submitted an edit to the title of your post considering it was somewhat misleading to the problem you are having. You were not trying to update an `_id` field as indicated but rather your Python Dictionary definition was incompatible with the BSON spec.

In this line:

```
data = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': {1: {'a': 'B'}}, '_id': 'AB123456789'}
```

You have a numeric (integer) as the key value for, in Mongo terms, a document. Deriving from JSON, within the BSON spec this is not valid your keys **must** be Strings as required in the specification.

```
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: documents must have only string keys, key was 1
```

You need to keep all of your **keys** in your Python code as *strings* in order to be compliant.

```
data = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': {'1': {'a': 'B'}}, '_id': 'AB123456789'}
```

Changing the representation of the key to a string **fixes** the problem.

As a note, consider your document structure as there are several disadvantages of using this type of notation (if you want to access a *numerical* index ) in a MongoDB documents collection over using an array.

Comment: Ohhh! I think I understand it. Its not just the document key, but every key within the document. Thats what threw me. Thanks

Comment: key does not mean primary key (_id) it means any field name. key-value pairs, etc.